# Node not exporting connection to mongodb atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My connection works in general, but when I try to export the connection and use it in another module, I get the error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
at /Users/.../meet.js:7:20

here is my connection.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Replace the following with your Atlas connection string
const url = process.env.MONGODB_ADDRESS;
const client = new MongoClient(url);
const dbName = "MarketingScrape";

async function run() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log("Connected correctly to database server");
        return client.db(dbName);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
}

module.exports = run;
```

here is meet.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const db = require('./connect')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const ac = require("@antiadmin/anticaptchaofficial");
let collection = null;
db().then(c => {
    collection = c.collection('Meet')
});

(async () => {...
```

Comment: `const db = require('./connect')` is this correct?

Comment: solved this error by exporting `run()` and changing line 6 to `db.then`...